# CakePHP 2.1 making a jquery ajax call with Security component activated

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.1

**FINALLY** found the solution:

If anyone have this problem put this in your beforefilter.

```
$this->Security->unlockedActions = array('givestar');
```

And update libs to Cake 2.3

**The problem:**

I am struggling with the SECURITY component blackholing me on my ajax calls.

var id = 1;

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/messages/givestar/",
    data: {"id" : id},
    dataType: "json"
 });
```

I am only trying to send the ID for the controller to update the message where id=id

But Security component is Blackholing me on all my ajax calls.

Anyone know how I can make it work with security component activated??

Thanks!

You are awesome!

-Tom

Suggestions????

**UPDATE2**
I get an AUTH error from blackhole after some testing.

```
From Book: 
‘auth’ Indicates a form validation error, or a controller/action mismatch error.
```

I have double checked all ACO nodes, they are good. I am leaning against a FORM VALIDATION ERROR from Security component on my ajax call.

**UPDATE:**

AppController.php

```
public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth',
        'Session',
    'Security',
    'Cookie'
    );
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = 'blackhole';
}
public function blackhole($type) {
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('ERROR: %s',$type), 'flash/error');
}
```

MessagesController.php

```
 public $components = array('RequestHandler');

        public function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter();
        }

public function givestar() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
            if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {

                echo 'Working';
            }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: security component activated?? means you want to encrypt the `id` or hide it in the ajax call ?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html

Comment: aahhh my bad. Im not a cake php guy ..Im with Zend framework+Jquery.There are plenty of Cakephp experts in SO..you will find what you need shortly :)

Comment: I do not want to encrypt anything, but security component is protecting every POST from tampering. I have read about serializing the ajax call and using json to get past this, but I am not sure how to do it... Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In beforefilter:

```
$this->Security->unlockedActions = array('givestar');
```

Answer (score 2):

SecurityComponent line 396:

```
if (!isset($controller->request->data['_Token'])) {
    if (!$this->blackHole($controller, 'auth')) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So I guess if You want to secure this action You must send data with additional generated '_Token' key. This key is generated using Form->secure($fields) method (acctualy method generates hidden inputs with proper values).