# How to check session in ajax in Cakephp 2.0?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How to check session in ajax in Cakephp 2.0? I'm using ajax to fetch some records. But while in an idle mode for some time and try some ajax fetch, it redirects to 500 Error page. Its jus t because it doesn't have the session. How do I check before this ajax check.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your session get's destroyed. You can find more info here:
[ajax request ends CakePHP session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028263/ajax-request-ends-cakephp-session)

If you use the security component see:
[CakePHP 2.1 making a jquery ajax call with Security component activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869336/cakephp-2-1-making-a-jquery-ajax-call-with-security-component-activated)

Most of the time it's about the CakePHP configuration of security levels and the security component.